# Approximate the singular values of a certain random dot-product kernel matrix (in the sense of El Karoui, Cheng-Singer, etc.)

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, measure-concentration

- Let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function which is

  - "sufficiently smooth" (e.g $\mathcal C^3$) around $0$, and
  - "sufficiently integrable" (e.g integrable w.r.t $N(0,1)$).
- Let $d'$ and $d$ be positive integers tending to infinity such that $d'/d \to \rho \in (0,\infty)$.
- Let $X$ be an $d' \times d$ random matrix with iid rows $x_1,\ldots,x_D$ from $N(0,(1/d)I_d)$, let $\widetilde{X}$ be the $d'\times d$ random matrix with rows $\widetilde{x}_i := x_i/\|x_i\|$. Thus each $\widetilde{x}_i$ is uniformly distributed on the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^{d}$.
- For $x \sim N(0,(1/d)I_d)$ independent of $X$, define an $d' \times d'$ random psd matrices $B$ and $\widetilde{B}$ by
  $$
  \begin{split}
  b_{ij} &:= (x_i^\top x_j)\mathbb E_x[g(x^\top x_i)g(x^\top x_j)],\\
  \widetilde{b}_{ij} &:= (\widetilde{x}_i^\top \widetilde{x}_j)\mathbb E_x[g(\widetilde{x}^\top \widetilde{x}_i)g(\widetilde{x}^\top \widetilde{x}_j)].
  \end{split}
  $$

> **Question.** *Are the following true ?*
> $$
> \begin{split}
> \|B-g(0)^2 XX^\top\|_{op} &\overset{p}{\to} 0,\\
> \|\widetilde{B}-g(0)^2 \widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top\|_{op} &\overset{p}{\to} 0.
> \end{split}
> $$

### Empirical evidence

Here are results for some experiments with $d'=200$ and $d=300$, and different choices for $g$, both smooth and rough. Judgin from these observations, it seems the above question is affirmative!

[image]
[image]

### An sloppy attempt

> Let us give a heuristic (and incorrect!) argument why one would expect
> $$
> \|\widetilde{B}-g(0)^2\widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top\|_{op} \overset{p}{\to} 0
> $$
> to hold.

For simplicity of notation, let $w_i:=\widetilde{x}_i$ henceforth. Let the matrix $\widetilde{U}$ be the $n \times n$ random psd matrix be defined by $\widetilde{u}_{ij} := \mathbb E_z[g(z^\top w_i)g(z^\top w_j)]$, where $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_d)$ is uniform on the unit-sphere on $\mathbb R^d$, and independent of the $w_i$'s.

> Note that $\widetilde{B}$ the Hadamard product of $\widetilde{U}$ with $\widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top$.

Now, due to rotational-invariance, we may write $\widetilde{u}_{ij} = u_d(z_i^\top z_j)$, where $u_d:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ is defined by
$$
u_d(t) := \mathbb E_z[g(z_1)g(tz_1+(1-t^2)^{1/2} z_2)].
$$
Thus, $\widetilde{B}$ is a dot-product kernel matrix, via an envelop function $u_d$ which varies with the dimension $d$. This dependence on $d$ is bad news for us.

> *Let us ignore the dependence of $u_d$ on $d$. Of course, this is **incorrect** (and will be the only sloppy part of our arguments), but let's do it anyways.*

We can then invoke Theorem 2.3 of [El Karoui '10](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-38/issue-1/The-spectrum-of-kernel-random-matrices/10.1214/08-AOS648.full) to get that $\|\widetilde{U}-A\|_{op} \overset{p}{\to} 0$, where
$$
A := u_d(0) 1_{d'}1_{d'}^\top + u_d'(0)\widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top + \gamma I_{d'},
$$
with $\gamma := u_d(1)-u_d(0)-u_d'(0)$.

Finally, using exponential-in-$d$ concentration of $z_1^2 + z_2^2$, it is to see that

> **Fact**. *If $G:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is  a continuous function, then $\mathbb E_z[G(z_1,z_2)] \to G(0,0)$.*

We deduce that if our $g$ is $\mathcal C^1$ at $0$, then

> $$
> \begin{split}
> u_d(1) &= \mathbb E_z[g(z_1)^2] \to g(0)^2,\\
> u_d(0) &=\mathbb E_z[g(z_1)g(z_2)] \to g(0)^2,\\
> u_d'(0) &= \mathbb E_z[z_1 g(z_1)g'(z_2)] \to 0,\\
> \gamma &= u_d(1)-u_d(0)-u_d'(0) \to 0,
> \end{split}
> $$

from which it would follow that $\|\widetilde{U}-g(0)^2 1_{d'}1_{d'}\|_{op} \overset{p}{\to} 0$, and so $\|\widetilde{B}-g(0)^2 \widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top\|_{op} \overset{p}{\to} 0$, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

> **Claim (Nonasymptotic result under smoothenss condition).** *Suppose $g$ is $\mathcal C^5$ at $0$ and that $d'$ and $d$ are sufficiently large with $c_1 \le n'/d \le c_2$ for some absolute constants $0 < c_2 \le c_2 < \infty$. Then w.p $1-e^{-Cd}$, it holds that*
> $$
> \|\widetilde{B}-g(0)^2\widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top\|_{op} = o_d(1).
> $$

Of course, ideally, one would want to work with much less regularity (e.g think of $g(z) := 1 / (|z| + 1)$ in the experiments above).

---

*Proof.* Indeed, let $g(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5 +  \mathcal O(x^6)$ be its Maclaurin approximation of order $5$. Fix $i,j \in [n]$, and let $a := \widetilde{x}_i = x_i/\|x\|$, $b := \widetilde{x}_j = x_j/\|x\|$, and $t := a^\top b$. Note that $|t| \le 1$ unconditionally.

By linearity of expectation, we have $\widetilde{u}_{ij} := \mathbb E_w[g(w^\top a)g(w^\top b)] = c_{ij} + \mathcal O(1/d^3)$, where

$$
c_{ij} := \sum_{n=0}^5\sum_{m=0}^5 a_0 a_m \mathbb E[(w^\top a)^n(w^\top b)^m].
$$

On the other hand, for any $n,m \ge 0$, we have

> **Fact.** *$\mathbb E_w[(w^\top a)^n(w^\top b)^m]=0$ if $n$ and $m$ have different parities, and otherwise*
> $$
> \mathbb E_w[(w^\top a)^n(w^\top b)^m] = \frac{n!m!\Gamma(d/2)}{2^{n/2+m/2}\Gamma(d/2+n/2+m/2)}\sum_k \frac{t^k}{(n/2-k/2)!(m/2-k/2)!},
> $$
> *where the sum is over all $k \in \{0,\ldots,\min(n,m)\}$ which have the same parity as $n$ and $m$.*

Thus, $c_{ij}$ is a polynomial in $t$ of degree at most 5. The constant term (i.e the coefficient of $t^0$) in this polynomial is

$$
c_{ij}[t^0] = a_0^2 + \sum_{n,m}a_na_m\frac{n!m!}{2^{n/2+m/2}(n/2)!(m/2)!} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2+n/2+m/2)}
$$

where the sum is over even $n,m \in \{0,\ldots,5\}$ not both equal to $0$.
For any such $n$ and $m$, we have $n/2 + m/2 \ge 1$ and so

$$
\dfrac{\Gamma(d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2+n/2+m/2)} \le \dfrac{\Gamma(d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2+1)} = \frac{2}{d}.
$$
We conclude that $c_{ij}[t^0] = a_0^2 + \mathcal O(1/d)$ for large $d$.

Similarly, for any $k \in \{1,\ldots,5\}$, we have that the coefficient of $t^k$  in $c_{ij}$ is
$$
c_{ij}[t^k] = \sum_{n,m}a_na_m\frac{n!m!}{2^{n/2+m/2}(n/2-k/2)!(m/2-k/2)!} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2+n/2+m/2)}
$$
where the sum is over $n,m \in \{k,\ldots,5\}$ which have same parity as $k$. Note that for any such $n,m$ we have $n/2+m/2 \ge k$, and so
$$
\dfrac{\Gamma(d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2+n/2+m/2)} \le \dfrac{\Gamma(d/2)}{\Gamma(d/2+k)}=\dfrac{1}{(d+2(k-1))(d+2(k-1))\ldots d} \le \frac{1}{d^k},
$$
We deduce that $u_{ij}[t^k] = \mathcal O(1/d^k)$ for large $d$, and so because $\|\widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top \|_{op} = \mathcal O(1)$ w.p $1-e^{-Cd}$ (by way of classical nonasymptotic RMT), we deduce that

$$
\|\widetilde{U}-(a_0^2+\mathcal O_d(1/d)) 1_{d'}1_{d'}^\top\|_{op}=o_{d}(1).
$$
Finally, since $(1_{d'}1_{d'}^\top) \circ (\widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top) = \widetilde{X}\widetilde{X}^\top$, the claim follows.  $\quad\quad\quad\quad\Box$